# Part of code in python game project not working?

Tags: python

in my Python game code i made a function that's meant to return another function once the requirements have been completed but it doesn't seem to work and i'm not sure what else to try? her's that bit of code:

```
def Allfightcoords():
    global xpos, ypos
    if xpos == 1 and ypos == 7:
        return event_2()
    elif xpos == 4 and ypos == 3:
        return event_2()
    elif xpos == 5 and ypos == 5:
        return event_2()
    elif xpos == 7 and ypos == 2:
        return event_2()
    elif xpos == 8 and ypos == 4:
        return event_2()

Allfightcoords()
```

the xpos and ypos commands are just the coords the player should be on to trigger a certain event, in this case event 2.
Any advice on what to change or what i've done wrong? Much appreciated.

Comment: using `()` calls the functions, if you want to return the function object you need to use `return func` not `return func()`

Comment: You don't return a function, but the return value of the function, as you call it. But I'm really not sure that it is what you really meant here, and " it doesn't seem to work" is not a clear enough description of your problem. Please clarify.

Comment: what i meant by it doesn't work is when i go on those coords when i run the game, nothing happens. no error, just nothing.

Comment: And how are you running this game? Is it true that every time you change the coordinates, this function is called?

Comment: yep, all the other functions are working on the specific coords except this part

Comment: Can you add the code where this function is actually being called, and tell us about your expected outcome?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return the function "event_2", just write

```
return event_2
```

without parentheses. This will actually return the function object.

Comment: tried it without the parenthesis and the function still didn't work

Comment: What's the exception you get?

Comment: no exception, just when i go on that certain coords nothing happens, it just prints back "what would you like to do now?" which should print back after the event has happened

Comment: It looks as if you'd forgotten to return in some function definition. However, if this happened in event_2 then when you tried 'event_2()', you should have got an exception for calling a NoneType object. I guess, you either forgot to call the function, or to return in case you've used closures wrapping your events.

Answer (score 0):

To fetch a function which you want to later invoke, you return the reference to the function itself without braces.

```py
return myFunction
```

This is different to what you are doing, where including braces will call the function and then return the value from the function call.

```py
def Allfightcoords():
    global xpos, ypos
    if xpos == 1 and ypos == 7:
        return event_1
    elif xpos == 4 and ypos == 3:
        return event_2
    elif xpos == 5 and ypos == 5:
        return event_3
    elif xpos == 7 and ypos == 2:
        return event_4
    elif xpos == 8 and ypos == 4:
        return event_5

functionToInvoke = Allfightcoords() # Fetch the function.
functionToInvoke() # Call the function here.
```

Comment: Just tried this, an error came up saying line 333, in <module>
    functionToInvoke()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable